# Safari not prompt to install the SSL certificate with Charles?

Tags: charles-proxy

when Safari browse to https://chls.pro/ssl，it just show 
"---- BEGIN CERTIFICATE----
***some encryption text***
---- END CERTIFICATE----".

Answer (score 0):

in the SSL submenu in the Tool menu in Charles. if you selected the rewrite submenu, disable the submenu can fix the problem.